# How to fix "HTTP 405" when posting to a Google Script?

Tags: http, google-apps-script, lua, roblox, http-status-code-405

I am trying to make a post request to a Google Script from a ROBLOX Server, but I am getting an "HTTP 405" error. It works fine from Postman (software I was using to test HTTP Post requests), but when I post from the ROBLOX Server, I get an HTTP 405 error. What can I do to fix this?

Google Script Code

```
function doPost(e) {
    Logger.log("running");
    handleFunction(e.parameter);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

ROBLOX Code

```
return function(args)
    pcall(function()
        --Get the timestamp
        args.Time = os.date("!*t").year .. ":" .. os.date("!*t").month .. ":" .. os.date("!*t").day .. " " .. os.date("!*t").hour .. ":" .. os.date("!*t").min .. ":" .. os.date("!*t").sec;
        args = HttpService:JSONEncode(args);
        HttpService:PostAsync(dbScript,args);
    end);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [forum](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/http-error-405/198221/7), maybe Google banned roblox from sending data to google sheets, as it was probably abused by others. Also try to put the URL you copied into the Roblox module into your browser. *From the script editor Publish -> Deploy as web app should list your current URL. If they banned Roblox’s servers, this will work.*

Comment: Looked like they banned ROBLOX. Guess I'll make a proxy or something.